# Entity framework sql stored procedure with where clause

Tags: sql, entity-framework

**Executing stored procedure with Entity Framework (EF) returning all records, even though I applied paging, sorting, filtering.**

Below is the code.

```
var result = base.Context.proc_App_Contracts_All(Customer_No).AsQueryable()
                .Where(filterExpression == null ? e => e.Contract_Number == e.Contract_Number : filterExpression)
                .OrderBy(sortExpression)
                .Skip((request.Page - 1) * request.PageSize)
                .Take(request.PageSize)
                .ToList());
```

I think the reason is EF filtering records on application level (in case of stored procedure) not on database level, that's why EF fetches all the records to the application and then apply the sorting and filtering etc.

So here I wants to know that is there any way to execute stored procedure in same way just like we query to a table or view in EF which eventually makes a query wrapper around your query or Should I convert my stored procedure to view.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: Please help me to get rid of it.